# How to combine 2 potentiometers together?

Tags: wiring, potentiometer

I have 2 amplifiers and each has its own variable volume pot on them to control the audio volume. How can I wire both of those to a single pot that will work with both?

Comment: Are the amplifiers identical?

Comment: [Dual potentiometer.](http://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Product_10001_10001_2181466_-1)  Two electrically independent pots on the same shaft.

Comment: they are not identical. can i still use a dual potentiometer?

Comment: @user2570937  Edit your answer to provide the details and context, please.  The question in its present form can't be answered with certainty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are feeding the same audio signal to both amps then use a common potentiometer on the input signal and take the wiper output to both amplifiers. The volume controls on the individual amplifiers need to be set to a level appropriate for full loudness in your situation.

If the audio sources are different then use a dual-gang pot.

Also note that you will need to choose a pot that is low enough in value (lowish resistance) so that the input impedances of two parallel inputs (case 1) or individual inputs (case 2) do not cause the pot adjustment to become very non-linear.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a project then you can open up the amps and determine:

1. If there is no current drawn from the potentiometer (it is not directly involved in an op amp circuit or something) then you can tap the output of one of them and connect it (and ground) to where the potentiometer would have been on the other amp.
2. If there is current drawn from the pot in some way, you will need to use a double pole potentiometer, one pole per amp.

If these are stereo amps, you will need to double up on both of the above.

If you are not looking for a project, you could probably achieve the behavior you want with something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002J226O) or similar that has the connectors you like. Then connect the output of this knob to the input of both amps and leave the volume knob on the amp itself in one spot (the maximum volume you want) and use this knob to control both.